# Bone structure alteration in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, episode-identification

I do remember that there was an episode of Clone Wars where Obi-Wan used some procedure to alter his bone structure to disguise as a prisoner. I have multiple questions pertaining to the bone structure alteration:

1. In which episode(s) did the bone alteration occur?
2. Was there a name to this procedure?
3. Were there any known side effects to the procedure (i.e. was it temporary, did it come at the cost of bone diseases, etc?)

Comment: You seem to have more than one question here. The first will certainly be trivially included in the answer to the second, but the second and third are quite different. The answer to the third is almost certainly unknown, since the only canon appearance of this procedure was in a single *Clone Wars* arc.

Comment: I agree with Adamant. You should probably edit your question before angry people with spare closing flags wake up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "[Deception](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deception)"

The episode involved Obi-Wan posing as a bounty hunter to gain intelligence on a plot to assassinate Palpatine. As part of going undercover, he fakes his own assassination at the hands of a bounty hunter named Rako Hardeen, and then steals the man's identity (and appearance).

The procedure he undergoes is only referred to as a "facial transformation", and it is completely reversible (and is reversed a few episodes later).

This is the only episode in which the procedure appears (though Obi-Wan lives as Hardeen for four episodes in total), so information about it is scarce. There is no discussion of any adverse side-effects, aside from the obvious pain Obi-Wan endures while his *skull changes shape beneath his skin*. Considering Obi-Wan goes on to live to a ripe old age, clearly there are no long-term (or irreparable) side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

It was known as a “facial transformation program.” Whether it had a more technical name is uncertain. It appeared in the *Clone Wars* arc beginning with "Deception" and ending with "Crisis on Naboo."

> **2-1B surgical droid**: Facial transformation program loaded.
>
> <sub>*The Clone Wars*, “Deception”</sub>

This procedure appears to have been very much temporary, since Obi-Wan was restored to his previous appearance by the end of the story arc in which the procedure was introduced.