# Are there any Jedi Shadows in the new canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I have read in "The Jedi Path: A Manual For Students of the Force" of a specific specialization of Jedi Sentinels, the Jedi Shadows:

> The elite Jedi Shadows are widely respected members of the Sentinels. The role of Jedi Shadows is to seek out and vanquish any traces of the dark side, requiring them to be spies and saboteurs. Jedi Shadows prize the mission above all else, and often must make moral compromises that would be unpleasant for other members of the Order.

These Jedi used a wider range of Force powers, even some considered to be Dark Side abilities. They specialized in sabotage, assassinations, and covert ops.

Are there any examples of a Jedi Shadow in the current canon?

Comment: Its' probably worth keeping in mind that Jedi Shadows/Sentinels/Guardians etc. come from the world of gaming, as such it's mostly just meant to serve player combat mechanics and doesn't necessarily translate to the way Jedi are actually supposed to operate. As a rule, with rare exception Jedi don't overly specialise to such a narrow degree.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, nothing *quite* like this exists in canon. The Jedi certainly aren't shy about undercover operations (and we see at least [one such assignment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147901/31051) in *The Clone Wars* cartoon), or with occasionally working with bounty hunters and pirates, but ordinarily they don't "[become the mask](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BecomingTheMask)"<sup>1</sup> and engage in more distasteful criminal endeavours.

However, the canon novel *Dark Disciple* gives us one possible example, and the closest I can think of in the new canon:

### Master Quinlan Vos

Vos specializes in deep cover assignments in organized crime rings, which forces him to do some damned distasteful things in the line of duty; however, the canon novel *Dark Disciple* is slightly unique, because the Jedi Council orders him to assassinate Count Dooku:

> "A course of action that we reluctantly deemed necessary" said Mace. Vos's gaze flickered to Yoda, doubtless curious as to why Windu spoke instead of the head of the Council. "There's no way to phrase this other than bluntly. Master Vos — the Council wants you to assassinate Count Dooku."
>
> <sup>*Dark Disciple* Chapter 3</sup>

Although he isn't trained (by the Jedi) in the use of Dark Side techniques, he and his partner on the mission (Asajj Ventress) agree that tapping into the Dark Side is the only way for him to be strong enough to stand a chance, and he goes far enough along that path to kill an innocent creature, the last of its kind:

> Vos drew in great, ragged gulps of air, his body straining with tension. He heard Ventress's voice shouting at him, "What are you waiting for? Kill it, Vos!"
>
> *[...]*
>
> "Ventress," he called, still controlling the Sleeper, "it may be the last of its kind!"
>
> *[...]*
>
> He made his choice.
>
> He focused on his earlier fear: the helplessness he had felt, and his anger at it. He narrowed his eyes, calling up the hatred and rage, feeling them burst into him, white-hot and so very powerful.
>
> This was an enemy. This was Count Dooku. Vos extended his hand, slowly, deliberately, taking the time to truly experience the emotions as they translated from thought to action.
>
> *Die*.
>
> <sup>*Dark Disciple* Chapter 17</sup>

Without wishing to spoil the rest of the novel, this turns out to be an *astonishingly* bad plan, and the Jedi Council quickly comes to regret following through with it.

---

<sup>1</sup> TVTropes link; it's dangerous to go alone